# Java REST Client - javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am using Java 1.7 and am trying to create a client to query a REST api.

However, I get the following error when executing the client. I put a breakpoint in the REST service, and it is never reached.

**Error**

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient
```

**Question**

Any ideas how I fix the client?

**Code**

**pom.xml**

```
    <!-- JAX-RS 2.x Client RI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Client.java**

```
import javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

private static final String approvalSubmitUrl = "http://localhost:8081/rest/approvals-status/{evaluationRequestId}";

public Object getStatus(String evaluationRequestId, EvaluationProvidedNotification providedNotification) {
    logger.info(approvalSubmitUrl);
    EvaluationProvidedNotificationDTO evaluationProvidedNotificationDTO = new EvaluationProvidedNotificationDTO();
    map(providedNotification, evaluationProvidedNotificationDTO);
    try {
        logger.info("Sending request to get status from " + approvalSubmitUrl + " (nexct-approval-service)");
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(approvalSubmitUrl);
        Response response = target.queryParam("evaluationRequestId", evaluationRequestId)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.json(evaluationProvidedNotificationDTO));
        StatusResponse statusResponse = response.readEntity(StatusResponse.class);
        logger.info("Successfully got the status: " + statusResponse.status );
    }
    catch (BadRequestException refused) {
        logger.error("Request to: " + approvalSubmitUrl + " REFUSED: " + refused.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Failed to get status from " + approvalSubmitUrl, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The service is just for reference, as I am sure the error is a result of a mistake in the client.

**Service.java** (Springboot with Java 14)

```
@PostMapping(value = "/rest/approvals-status/{evaluationRequestId}", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<StatusDTO> getStatus(@PathVariable String evaluationRequestId, @RequestBody EvaluationProvidedNotificationDTO providedNotificationDTO) {
    StatusDTO status = new StatusDTO();
    status.setEvaluationRequestId(evaluationRequestId);
    if (providedNotificationDTO.outcome == EvaluationProvidedNotificationDTO.Evaluation.Approved) {
        if (pendingApprovals(evaluationRequestId)) {
            status.setStatus(StatusDTO.Status.Wait);
        } else {
            status.setStatus(StatusDTO.Status.Proceed);
        }
    } else {
        status.setStatus(StatusDTO.Status.Wait);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(status);
}
```

This is the object to be posted:

**EvaluationProvidedNotificationDTO.java**

```
public class EvaluationProvidedNotificationDTO {

    public enum Evaluation {
        Approved, Rejected;
    }

    //any contraints on the request for example cost constraints
    public List<Serializable> constraints;

    //the outcome of the evaluation
    public Evaluation outcome;

    //any messages that the evaluator wants to send to the requestor
    public String messageToRequestor;

    public List<Serializable> getConstraints() {
        return constraints;
    }

    public void setConstraints(List<Serializable> constraints) {
        this.constraints = constraints;
    }

    public Evaluation getOutcome() {
        return outcome;
    }

    public void setOutcome(Evaluation outcome) {
        this.outcome = outcome;
    }

    public String getMessageToRequestor() {
        return messageToRequestor;
    }

    public void setMessageToRequestor(String messageToRequestor) {
        this.messageToRequestor = messageToRequestor;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the issue may be related to trying to convert a POJO to Json. With the `Entity.json(...` or the media type. But I am not sure what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by converting the POJO to JSON:

```
        Invocation.Builder builder = target.request();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(evaluationProvidedNotificationDTO);
        Entity entity = Entity.entity(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        Response response = builder.post(entity);
        StatusResponse statusResponse = response.readEntity(StatusResponse.class);
```